# phonegap build and pushwoosh gets error aps environment not found?

Tags: phonegap-build, pushwoosh

I´m trying to get the pushwoosh plugin to work in a phonegap build app and all I get is an alert error that the aps environment is not found.

This is the steps I took.

1. Created a new appID that I enabled push notification on.
2. Created a new APNs Development Certificate. And downloaded it.
3. Created a new mobile provisioning profile and downloaded it and installed it on my phone.
4. Checked the mobile provisioning profile that it had "aps-environment" and "developer" in it.
5. In key chain I rightclicked the aps certificate and exported a .cer and a .p12 file and uploaded them to my newly created application on pushwoosh.com
6. I wrote the pushwoosh application id in my index file and the right id in the config file(same as in my mobile provisioning file)
7. I rightclicked my iPhone Developer Certificate in key chain and exported a .p12 file for phonegap and called it mypushapp.p12.
8. I created a new key at phonegap build and uploaded the mypushapp.p12 and the mobile provising file and then I build my app.

The app itself works as it should, but I get this aps error that it failed to register?

In my index file I init pushwoosh in the deviceready function and this is the pushwooshcode that I have.

```
function initPushwoosh() {
            alert("init pushwoosh");
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    pushNotification.onDeviceReady();

    pushNotification.registerDevice({alert:true, badge:true, sound:true, pw_appid:"5FB5C-E3F1F", appname:"newpushtest"},
                                    function(status) {
                                        var deviceToken = status['deviceToken'];
                                        console.warn('registerDevice: ' + deviceToken);
                                    },
                                    function(status) {
                                        console.warn('failed to register : ' + JSON.stringify(status));
                                        navigator.notification.alert(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
                                    });

    pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0);

    pushNotification.getTags(function(tags) {
                                console.warn('tags for the device: ' + JSON.stringify(tags));
                             },
                             function(error) {
                                console.warn('get tags error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                             });

    //start geo tracking. PWTrackSignificantLocationChanges - Uses GPS in foreground, Cell Triangulation in background. 
    pushNotification.startLocationTracking('PWTrackSignificantLocationChanges',
                                    function() {
                                           console.warn('Location Tracking Started');
                                    });

    document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
                                var notification = event.notification;

                                navigator.notification.alert(notification.aps.alert);

                                //to view full push payload
                                //navigator.notification.alert(JSON.stringify(notification));

                                pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0);
                              });
}
```

I don´t know where I go wrong so any input appreciated thanks.